# Newlines from attribute text in pseudo element's content

Tags: html, css, attributes, newline, css-variables

With `content: attr(attribute-name)` it is possible to add a pseudo element (`:before` or `:after`) with text content from an element's attribute. Besides that the `content` property of the pseudo element does allow new lines via the `\A` character within the content of the pseudo element, too:

```
content: attr(attribute-name1) '\a' attr(attribute-name2)
```

What I now want is to be able to control the position and existence of newline characters within the value of a single attribute containing a multi line text. The text is defined by the user and thus out of my control.

**Element:**

```
<span data-usertext="Some random text with \a some newlines"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
span:after {
  content: attr(data-usertext);
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Sadly this does not work: The `\a` is printed out as if it is a simple character sequence. I also tried `\r`, `\n` and `<br />` out of curiosity.

**How can I get the newlines from the attribute interpreted as such without using Javascript?**

A fiddle I used to try around: https://jsfiddle.net/dWkdp/3039/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using HTML you need to consider `&#10;` for a new line instead of `\A` that is used with CSS. You need to also add `white-space:pre`

```css
span:after {
  content: attr(data-usertext);
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<span data-usertext="Some random text with &#10; some newlines"></span>
```

You can also do this:

```css
span:after {
  content: attr(data-usertext);
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<span data-usertext="Some random text with &NewLine; some newlines"></span>
```

Check this link for more details: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: Thank you! That solves the problem. I totally forgot about the HTML entities.
I added the missing `white-space: pre` as I forgot to insert it from the fiddle.

Comment: I made progress with my code and now I also need to set the attribute via JS (`span.dataset.usertext = "Some new &10; user text"`). When doing so the entities in the text such as `&10;` are not resolved. Instead they get interpreted as text, again (see https://jsfiddle.net/dWkdp/3042/). Any idea?

Comment: @SebastianBarth yes with JS also it's not the same as HTML, let me remember the trick and will let you know ;)

Comment: I found a solution but it is not that nice: The problem is that my text is not parsed as HTML. Instead it is parsed as text and also set as text to the attribute. To get it parsed as HTML I just created a new element set its HTML to my text containing the entities and fetched it again as HTML: `const div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = 'foo &10; bar'; span.dataset.usertext = div.innerHTML;` – Of course this introduces a security problem that forces me to first filter the text. I hope you have a better idea! See https://jsfiddle.net/dWkdp/3044/

Comment: @SebastianBarth yes, I am afraid this will be your only way actually.